How to override the color of the title of the toolpad-mui
I am new to UI development and trying to use react/ui/javascript. I am developing a dashboard and using the MUI Toolpad.
The default color that the MUI Toolpad takes is the primary color but I want to override with some other color. I checked the theming option but I am not clear how to specify the cssVariables that overrides the default color.
I am using a custom theme in a json file and applying that theme, but it is not overriding the color. -
"typography": {
    "fontFamily": "\"Droid Sans\", \"Helvetica\", \"Arial\", sans-serif",
    "allVariants": {
      "color": "#212121"
    }
},

Could anyone please provide an example.

You can change the title theme by simply giving Typography tag where you are writing your title with your styling, I am using tailwind CSS you can use style attribute too.
import { Typography } from "@mui/material";
import { AppProvider } from "@toolpad/core/react-router-dom";

<AppProvider
      branding={{
        title: (
          <Typography variant="h6" className="!font-bold font-sans">
            Your Title
          </Typography>
        ),
        logo: <img src="/logo.png" alt="logo" />,
      }}
>
</AppProvider>

